# what does num%2 mean in java?

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements, modulus

this is the code fragment. I'm not too sure what num%2 is though. % would give the remainder, so does that mean that the remainder of num must be 2?

```
int num = 1, max = 20;
while (num < max)
{
     if (num%2 == 0)
          System.out.println(num);
     num++;
}
```

Comment: No, it clearly "says" `num%2 == 0`. So, the remainder of dividing the number by 2 should be 0 (evenly divisible by 2).

Comment: If Condition here is for checking if the number is a Even or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
num%2==0
```

means the remainder of num divided by two which if something is divided by two the only remainder it could have is either 0 or 1, so its taking the remainder of dividing num by 2 and checking if it is equal to 0